# How to show a notification at a speicific page based on visitor's country?

Tags: commerce

I need to notify (only notify) users ordering through my Drupal Commerce based website that we don't serve their country, if they are not from a specific country. How can I achieve this on the checkout page only?

I know smart IP module can help me determine the country per IP, how can I implement the notification at the checkout page, before user proceed with his order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can sort out the Smart IP bid and you get the user's country then you can use [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) and [Context GeoIP](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_geoip).

Create a new Context where you can choose the countries you don't deliver as a condition and show block as a reaction. Your block might be a modal box informing your users.

[image]